# MariaDB slow LEFT JOIN on binary UUID-columns

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

I have a very long running query (and subsequent non-professional attempts of improved queries) involving LEFT JOINs against a MariaDB.

- engine is InnoDB
- tables are pb_work (4 columns) and pb_instance (9 columns)
- both tables contain 1.000.000 rows (theoretically one work can have many instances, this is just for testing purposes)
- all involved id-columns are `binary(16)` (representing UUIDs)

1. The initial query was the following:

```
SELECT * FROM pb_work LEFT JOIN pb_instance pi on pb_work.id = pi.work_id;
```

(Takes ~1m24s)

2. Naively I tried to limit that as my use-case allows to request stuff in batches:

```
SELECT * FROM pb_work LEFT JOIN pb_instance pi on pb_work.id = pi.work_id LIMIT 300;
```

(Takes ~55s, honestly has me wondering why it is faster at all as I thought the join happens first anyways before the limiting)

3. Assuming that's probably too many entries in the first table:

```
SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT * FROM pb_work LIMIT 300) as subq
             LEFT JOIN pb_instance pi on subq.id = pi.work_id;
```

(Takes ~1m, has me wondering why it's slower; executing the inner select alone runs 94ms)

EXPLAIN-output for the first and second version:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pb_work | ALL |  |  |  |  | 1113950 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pi | ALL | IDX_CA4ED742BB3453DB | IDX_CA4ED742BB3453DB | db.pb_work.id |  | 1 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |

EXPLAIN-output for the third version:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | ALL |  |  |  |  | 300 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pi | ref | IDX_CA4ED742BB3453DB | IDX_CA4ED742BB3453DB | 16 | subq.id | 1 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
| 2 | DERIVED | pb_work | ALL |  |  |  |  | 1113950 |  |

There are indexes on those tables. Output of `SHOW indexes FROM ...` omitting unrelated indexes.

pb_work:

| Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 0 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |

pb_instance:

| Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 0 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| 1 | IDX_CA4ED742BB3453DB | 1 | work_id | A | 0 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |

I have very little knowledge about DBMS so I can't do a lot with that information.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: increasing [join_buffer_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/block-based-join-algorithms/#size-of-join-buffers) will help with the BNL joins. With query 3, make the subselect `ORDER BY id` and only retrieve `id`. It also looks like your `id` is a secondary index rather than a primary. A primary will probably perform better.

Comment: Okay, ill check that! Thank you for your input!